# i am getting 4 errors along with 2 warnings for my GrossPaySession program

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have followed my professor's step by step guide and i am getting lots of errors. i looked at the attributes to match my previous assignment and i am stuck. i have two web forms that i think are supposed to work in Conjunction with each other. For now i am working on the first web form of the program.

the first code is the source code from the Grosspayapp designer source code. i get a single error. The error is CS0436 which states  the type 'Grosspayapp' in 'C:\Users\david\source\repos\GrosspaySession\Grosspayapp.aspx' conflicts with the imported type 'Grosspayapp' in 'GrosspaySession, Version = 1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null' Using the type defined in 'C:\Users\david\source\repos\GrosspaySession\Grosspayapp.aspx'

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Grosspayapp.aspx.cs" Inherits="Grosspayapp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <strong><span class="style1">Gross Pay Program</span></strong><br />
        <br />

            <img alt="" src="pie.png" style="height: 113px; width: 141px" /></div>
    <p>
        Name
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"  Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        Hours 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txthours" runat="server" Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        Rate
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server" Width="68px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdcompute" runat="server" Text="Compute Gross Pay" OnClick="Compute_Click"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        Gross Pay
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtgrosspay" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        </p>

    </form>

         <form action = "summary.aspx" method = "post"> 
        <input type = "submit" value = "Report" />    
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

the next code is the code from grosspayapp.aspx.cs which i get the following errors 'txtname','txthours','txtrate', and 'txtgrosspay' does not exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Grosspayapp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Compute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name;
        String shours, srate;
        int hours;
        double rate, grosspay;

        name = txtname.Text;

        shours = txthours.Text;
        hours = Convert.ToInt32(shours);

        srate = txtrate.Text;
        rate = Convert.ToDouble(srate);

        grosspay = hours * rate;
        txtgrosspay.Text = grosspay.ToString();

        Session["NameCookie"] = name;
        Session["HoursCookie"] = hours;
        Session["RateCookie"] = rate;
        Session["GrosspayCookie"] = grosspay;

    }
}
```

Comment: You have two `</div>`.  One is at the end of  `<img....` and one is before `</form>`

Comment: Looks like you have a class Grosspayapp from another library and that conflicts with aspx code behind class. You might want to have you page named as `Grosspaypage.aspx` and accordingly the code behind class.

Comment: getting rid of the 2nd </div> line before </form> gets rid of the one warning thank you.

Comment: getting rid of the 2nd </div> line before </form> gets rid of the one warning thank you. Also when i change that as well the grosspaypage.aspx i changed the code file name to match but i am still stuck on the same errors. CS0436 and the 'txtname','txtrate','txtgrosspay', and 'txthours'

Answer (score 0):

So the way i fixed the error is from the following. I deleted the grosspay designer.cs file within the web form. After that i clicked the grosspay.aspx, click project, and Convert to Web application. It will pop up with a prompt and it will have a yes or no. Click Yes and i built the program and it gave me no errors on that webform. The issue seems to be related to the Control. The control wasn't able to get ahold of my code so when i followed these steps it worked.